# XDG RUNTIME DIR not set error encountered while trying to use KDE Partition Manager

Tags: partitioning, sudo, xdg

Ubuntu dabbler here with quite the situation.

I'm using Lubuntu 19.10 and I was trying to reformat a flash drive. Running the KDE Partition Manager doesn't allow me to do anything other than view the partitions I have.

I try opening open KDE Partition Manager in bash:

```
sudo partitionmanager
```

and it prints out this:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
Loaded backend plugin:  "pmlibpartedbackendplugin"
"Using backend plugin: pmlibpartedbackendplugin (1)"
"Scanning devices..."
getting smart status failed for  "/dev/mmcblk0" :  Operation not supported
"Device found: MMC hC8aP>"
"Partition ‘/dev/mmcblk0p2’ is not properly aligned (last sector: 122,142,194, modulo: 1,523)."
getting smart status failed for  "/dev/mmcblk0boot0" :  Operation not supported
"Device found: Generic SD/MMC Storage Card"
"LibParted Exception: /dev/mmcblk0boot0: unrecognised disk label"
getting smart status failed for  "/dev/mmcblk0boot1" :  Operation not supported
"Device found: Generic SD/MMC Storage Card"
getting smart status failed for  "/dev/mmcblk1" :  Operation not supported
"LibParted Exception: /dev/mmcblk0boot1: unrecognised disk label"
"Device found: SD GD4QT"
"Scan finished."
```

After this I usually just exit out of the partition software.

Cursory searches have led me to believe that several things are at work here. The first is that my sudo and/or environment is set up incorrectly. Second that the improper alignment of my partitions is partially to blame.

The system in question is a HP Stream 11 (ak1012dx) which uses eMMC as opposed to a proper SSD. Hence the the OS and boot sits on the MMC hC8aP device. The SD GD4QT is a microSD card that I use for media storage it uses exfat which I added drivers for.

Hopefully the error isn't too egregious, but if it is I'm not adverse to reinstalling Linux.

Any advice, or better yet instructions and resources to fixing this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KDE Partition Manager should not be run with sudo. Older versions of KDE Partition Manager can use kdesu to relaunch as root. Newer versions (4.0 and newer) can properly use polkit for privilege escalation.

Ubuntu 19.10 still has an older version, so perhaps you should install kdesu. Once you have 20.04 it should just work.

Incorrect alignment can be fixed by moving or resizing partitions. Backup is strongly recommended.

You can ignore SMART status warnings. Your storage media simply does not support it.